# SwiftUI on iOS 15, strange warning of [UICollectionViewRecursion] when using contextMenu

Tags: swiftui, uicollectionview, ios15

[UICollectionViewRecursion] cv == 0x10481a000 Disabling recursion trigger logging

Comment: For me it's just a UICollection with compositional layout which generates this kind of log.

Comment: I too face this issue only on iOS 15, with UIKit. Works perfact with older iOS.
The problem is the app crashes for me!

Comment: Same issue here with a compositional layout.

Comment: Having the same issue with compositional layout. It seems to cause a crash when apps build configuration is in release mode but doesn't cause a crash when in debug mode. This causes app to crash in testflight or appstore!

Comment: I also notice that its just happening in iOS 15